# Extending the django User

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

this is my first question on stackoverflow. I am a beginner programmer and kind of have issues with programming logic.

My issue is that I have a model(which happens to be a form) which collects important information from the users, I want to be able relate this model with the individual user since it has the information about them that I need.

Any form of help is appreciated...By the way am using the Django web framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a new user, I suggest the following links:

[EXTENDING USER MODEL IN DJANGO](http://blog.tivix.com/2012/01/06/extending-user-model-in-django/)

[Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)

Generally, you create a normal model with a foreign key to the Django User model. Then add any other fields you would want to store for a user e.g. date of birth, website, favorite color, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Before 1.5: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-profiles, add a model that links OneToOne to the User model provided by Django and telling about that model in settings.py with the global AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE

After 1.5: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-custom-user, the previous method is deprecated. Now you have to fully customize the User model provided by Django.